# Can not log in on Stack Exchange App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-exchange

When trying to log on to the Stack Exchange app (since I have decided to become an active member rather than just browsing like I used to) I get the following error.

> 'key' is not valid 'access_token', not found.

I know the login info is correct and I have internet. My device is a Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 4.4.2 and I don't know if the rest is relevant but here it is anyway the Security software version is

> MDF v1.0 Release 3
>   VPN v1.4 Release 1

What do I do?

Comment: I'm trying a bunch of things like reinstalling and stuff. I mainly asked this question here because my first thought was to check if there was an easy solution before dragging out the computer to ask myself. Now future people will be able to solve this on their phone much faster ^^

Comment: Were you using the app in anonymous mode before you tried to login?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question. I never tried to post anything anonymously but I browsed a lot on it without logging in. When I finally tried to log on it didn't work and I posted here about it. Anything still unclear?

Comment: Btw is there any way to add new parts of SE to your account on the app? I had to log on in the browser to add meta so I could comment in the app -_-

Comment: @Pawnda if by "add new parts of SE to your account on the app?" you meant the site list, then inside the app, click the app logo to show a drawer menu, then on "Your Sites", click "Edit".

Comment: Wow awesome thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling the app works. I still don't know what was wrong so I don't know if that will always fix this but atleast now this error has been documented.